# Turn off play WS's verbose logging

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using Play WS in a regular scala project (i.e. not a play project). It appears to be printing all of the request and response headers to stdout making it difficult to debug things. Is there a way to toggle logging levels to stdout in Play WS?

I'm initiating it like this:

```
  val builder = new com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder()
  val client = new play.api.libs.ws.ning.NingWSClient(builder.build())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For others who find this question, the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852689/how-to-turn-off-netty-library-debug-output)

In short, create a "logback.xml" in src/main/resources and paste the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</root>

<logger name="com.ning.http.client" level="WARN"/>
</configuration>
```

What this xml is doing is explained if you follow the link.